# Simplify Select Query by Multiple Where Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I have select query on SQL Server 2012, with multiple where condition, here's my code :

```
   SELECT *
    FROM ##TempGet a
    LEFT JOIN Techs b ON a.TECH = b.TechID
    --LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (Serv,  'SELECT * FROM Hist order by histdate desc')) as c on a.CUST_ACCT = c.CUST_ACCT and c.HISTDATE >= a.sch_date
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ParamId, ParamType, Value1, Value2, Value3, Status, UpdateBy, UpdateDate FROM Parameter AS Parameter_3 WHERE (ParamType = 'SCABranch')) AS p ON LEFT (SCHAREAS, 1) = p.Value1
WHERE WSTAT = 'P/TC' 
AND (a.CUST_ACCT NOT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM NOT IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC))
OR (a.CUST_ACCT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM  IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC ) and a.sch_date not in (SELECT SCH_DATE from TC where CUST_ACCT = a.CUST_ACCT and OFFERNUM = a.Offernum))
OR (a.CUST_ACCT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM NOT IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC ) and a.sch_date not in (SELECT SCH_DATE from TC where CUST_ACCT = a.CUST_ACCT and OFFERNUM = a.Offernum))
```

the main issu is the where statment is too complicated,

```
 WHERE WSTAT = 'P/TC' 
    AND (a.CUST_ACCT NOT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM NOT IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC))
    OR (a.CUST_ACCT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM  IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC ) and a.sch_date not in (SELECT SCH_DATE from TC where CUST_ACCT = a.CUST_ACCT and OFFERNUM = a.Offernum))
    OR (a.CUST_ACCT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM NOT IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC ) and a.sch_date not in (SELECT SCH_DATE from TC where CUST_ACCT = a.CUST_ACCT and OFFERNUM = a.Offernum))
```

is it and combined with or is true? because some data I select not display, but it should there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

Are your brackets right?  In the three lines you have do you intend to 'OR' the three lines?  E.g. if  WSTAT = 'P/TC' should only one of the next three lines apply?  If so try them in brackets wrapping the 3

```
    WHERE WSTAT = 'P/TC' 
        AND  (  -- added bracket
           (a.CUST_ACCT NOT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM NOT IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC))
        OR (a.CUST_ACCT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM  IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC ) and a.sch_date not in (SELECT SCH_DATE from TC where CUST_ACCT = a.CUST_ACCT and OFFERNUM = a.Offernum))
        OR (a.CUST_ACCT IN (SELECT CUST_ACCT FROM TC) AND a.OFFERNUM NOT IN (SELECT OFFERNUM from TC ) and a.sch_date not in (SELECT SCH_DATE from TC where CUST_ACCT = a.CUST_ACCT and OFFERNUM = a.Offernum))  
             ) -- added bracket
```

It all comes down to predicate.  In simple terms a predicate is a fact statement generally in the where part of the query (can be done other places - in the ON part of a INNER/OUTER join HAVING clause.)  Each must be true and only if each predicate is true will you get a result.  So you are asking

```
        Get me <the columns I've listed>
    from <the tables I've listed>
    where 
      predicate 1 -- something you've written
      predicate 2 -- WHERE WSTAT = 'P/TC' 
      predicate 3 -- the AND line
      predicate 4 -- the OR line
      predicate 4 -- the other OR
```

and I suspect you want

```
        Get me <the columns I've listed>
    from <the tables I've listed>
    where 
      predicate 1 -- something you've written
      predicate 2 -- WHERE WSTAT = 'P/TC' 
      predicate 3 -- the AND line or the first OR or the 2nd OR
```

or

With a query logic question like this sometimes it helps to comment out a section of the query, almost always a where clause, to identify which is preventing your expected data from being returned.  Then review in depth the section in question.

Comment: by put bracket after and( statement a or statement b or statement c) it'll mean the query choose on of them, is it right?

Comment: Yes, I want something is  WSTAT = 'P/TC'  and  choose one condition which suitable by or statment